# Error Installing SSL Certificate via Let's Encrypt in Plesk

Tags: plesk

Invalid response from https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/6aiPKoMlUey-DC8yNvbvyZX7UaW5gISaGimggJnnICk.

Details:

Type: urn:acme:error:connection

Status: 400

Detail: dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for webmail.tradethon.com

please help for solving issue

Comment: Let's Encrypt prefers IPv6 over IPv4, while your browser probably cares a lot less. I would recommend you to try http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php for the domain that you get the error for.

Comment: yes. it gives error like                                                                                      
 AAAA DNS record  no AAAA record                                                                                                so how to solved problem ?

Comment: but my dns setting is                                                                           mail.tradethon.com. AAAA 2a02:c205:2023:2747::1                                              mail.tradethon.com.   A         93.104.214.158                                                                  tradethon.com. MX (10) mail.tradethon.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am adding DNS type A into my domain supplier dns settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RClNq.png)